# How to create a transparent cut in a view in react native?

Tags: react-native, styling

Is it possilbe to create a cut out in a view like the one in the picture and also add the border just by using styles? If so, how?
I tried styling it to that shape but i didn't mange to get it done.
[image: cut out image]